# MTU network path

Tags: networking, openvpn, embedded-linux, mtu

On an embedded device, there are a CPU and a LTE modem. 
They are connected together using serial port using GSM 07.10 multiplexing protocol. On the Muxed serial port, PPP handles the communication between the CPU and the telecom company. Between the telecom company and the customer, an openVPN is used.

We have to set MTU/MRU for MUX, PPP, OpenVPN. How would you choose the best values to ensure unfragmented communication and avoid to be bloqued by firewalls ?

```
CPU <> MUX over serial port <> MODEM
    <> PPP .                <> LTE <> Telecom company <> OpenVPN 
    <> IP .                                                      <> Customer
```

We choose the minimum at the OpenVPN side 576bytes. We know the MSS for OpenVPN is MTU-40bytes = 536 bytes What's the overhead of PPP and MUX ?